# Simple way to parse JSON in SQL 2014

Tags: json, sql-server, parsing, sql-server-2014

I'm looking for simple way in SQL 2014 (or lower), without external functions like [parseJSON](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/), to extract JSON values into string variables.

This is JSON:

```
declare @json nvarchar(1000) = '{"status":"ok","errmsg":0,"ordnumber":["123456","456789"]}'
```

I would like to get these values into 3 string variables:

```
declare @status varchar(50), @errmsg varchar(50), @ordnumber varchar(1000)

@status    => 'ok'
@errmsg    => '0'
@ordnumber => '123456,456789'
```

Comment: you've picked the wrong tool for the job. Parsing strings is not sql's strong suit. If you must do it in SQL Server prior to 2016 version, your best option is using a clr function.

Comment: The main job is data managing from SQL DB and sending to web service, this is just returning feedback. The mentioned function parseJSON is doing complete job but I want to avoid external functions for just one simple JSON string.

Comment: Well, as you can see for yourself in the link you've added to the question, it takes a long and cumbersome SQL code to parse JSON. If you know in advance the structure will always be the same, it will make your life easier - but if the only guarantee is that you will get a JSON structure then you are going to have to either use the function from the link or write the equivalent yourself. My suggestion would be to parse the json before it gets to the database and pass the data already parsed to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess then this is the simplest way to parse known JSON in SQL 2014 without external function ...

```
select @status = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@json,charindex('status',@json)+8,(charindex('errlog',@json)-2)-(charindex('status',@json)+8)),'"','')
select @errlog = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@json,charindex('errlog',@json)+8,(charindex('pl_number',@json)-2)-(charindex('errlog',@json)+8)),'"','')
select @parcelnum = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@json,charindex('pl_number',@json)+12,charindex(']}',@json)-(charindex('pl_number',@json)+12)),'"','')
```